ODI Scenario run twice with 1 second difference
A particular Scenario is scheduled to be executed by an Oracle Data Integrator (ODI) Agent at 08:00 PM.
This configuration has been running for a considerable period of months and quite suddenly the same identical Scenario is launched twice with a 1 second interval at 08:00 PM
I didn't find any solution

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
